# Requesting additional scopes returing incorect authorization code

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

This question is regarding Authorization code and `include_granted_scopes` in Google OAuth2 for incrementally changing scope.

In my web application, I ask for basic profile info as the scope:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email )

When a Gmail user signs up with us. After the user preforms some actions, I request additional scopes by setting `"include_granted_scopes=true"` in authorization url.

At this point, my authorization url looks like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=3490600xyz00-xyz....apps.googleusercontent.com&login_hint=hello@example.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/google-signup-callback&response_type=code&scope=https://mail.google.com https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state=da503933-8979-409b-988a-24a9542ad98a&redirect=label&include_granted_scopes=true
```

Now in the oauth callback I get the same "`Authorization code`" which I received when I did oauth earlier using basic profile scope. If I try to get the authorization token by calling "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" with "`grant_type`" set to "`authorization_code`", it returns

> "Code was already deemed".

Now how do I get the new "Auth token" and "Refresh token" which has the new scope? The old auth token does not have the new scope even if I refresh it using the old refresh token.

Comment: try adding prompt=consent

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I had to replace "approval_prompt=force" with "prompt=consent". If you can make it as answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt=consent is used to force the user to reauthenticate.